# Shinyproxy error 500 : Failed to start container / Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose, permission-denied, shinyproxy

The shinyproxy page is displayed and after authentication I can see the nav bar, 2 links to the 2 applications. Then, when I click on one of them, I got en error 500 / "Failed to start container"
In the stack, I can see :

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
```

Here is my configuration

**application.yml:**

```
proxy:
  title: Open Analytics Shiny Proxy
 # landing-page: /
  port: 8080
  authentication: simple
  admin-groups: scientists
  # Example: 'simple' authentication configuration
  users:
  - name: jack
    password: password
    groups: scientists
  - name: jeff
    password: password
    groups: mathematicians
  # Example: 'ldap' authentication configuration
  # Docker configuration
  #docker:
    #cert-path: /home/none
    #url: http://localhost:2375
    #port-range-start: 20000
  specs:strong text
  - id: 01_hello
    display-name: Hello Application
    description: Application which demonstrates the basics of a Shiny app
    container-cmd: ["R", "-e", "shinyproxy::run_01_hello()"]
    container-image: openanalytics/shinyproxy-demo
    access-groups: [scientists, mathematicians]
  - id: 06_tabsets
    container-cmd: ["R", "-e", "shinyproxy::run_06_tabsets()"]
    container-image: openanalytics/shinyproxy-demo
    access-groups: scientists

logging:
  file:
    shinyproxy.log
```

**shinyproxy-docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '2.4'
services:
    shinyproxy:
        container_name: shinyproxy
        image: openanalytics/shinyproxy:2.3.1
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - ./application.yml:/opt/shinyproxy/application.yml
        privileged: true
        ports:
            - 35624:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, workaround

`sudo chown $USER:docker /run/docker.sock`

However, I do not understand why this is needed, because `/run/docker.sock` was already `root:docker`.

This is under WSL2.

Comment: Just discovered my old thread.... Same under Ubuntu. SO replaces memory